# get scatterplot and figimage to work together

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am trying to add custom markers using 'figimage'. I first used scatterplot to add the data and was then going to overlay the images using a for loop. I have my marker image in a numpy array im

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(11.5, 5))
ax1.set_title('L2 PGD',fontsize=11, weight='bold')
points, = ax1.plot(data_x, data_y, 'r*')
x, y = points.get_data()
pixelPoints = ax1.transData.transform(np.vstack([x.astype('float64'), y.astype('float64')]).T)
for ii in range(x.shape[0]):
    print(pixelPoints[ii,:])
    fig.figimage(im,pixelPoints[ii,1],pixelPoints[ii,1],origin="upper")
```

I get the right "shape" of the scatter but the scale is off (my markers are the little grey boxes at the bottom middle)

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]